# My dates changed to a several digits combination - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a column `BirthDate` in my database. Somehow (unfortunately I can't say how and why) the dates became just to several digits and the column type is now `char`.
Sorry I can't tell more since it's a new project for me, and I just got some assignments to do.

For instance, a date is now represented as  `081101` (and it's not 08/11/2001, that's for sure)

Any chance I can get back to original? What are these digits at all? Any clue?

Comment: What was the data type of that column before? If it's `char` now, was is `date` before? If so, then apparently someone manually ALTERed the table and messed up your dates

Comment: do you have a database backup ?

Comment: Simple answer: If you are sure there has been an undesired change, restore your table from backup.

Comment: Is there anything else anywhere in the db that might give a clue to what this date was, such as a record of something they're signed up to when turning 18, and that table having a created date? I did consider that it might be the number of days since the SQL server min date 1/1/1753 but 81000 puts those birthdays around year 1800 which may not be correct. How about even a dummy test record of the original developer with his true birthday, now changed to X- if you can tell us his birthday and X we might be able to suggest. Ps I'd have assumed yymmdd rather than ddmmyy because it sorts correctly

Comment: If you don't know what that date represents, we don't either. If you don't have any logging, and no one is "owning up", then you may well need to use a backup; and then implement logging so that if it happens again you know who and when it happened.

Comment: There are many convoluted ways to store a date. Try to find out the interface that's storing or updating them to find out exactly how to value is computed. And definitely convert back the column to date/datetime type.

Comment: Ps, look at at least 200 rows- do the range of values you see imply anything? If the last two digits are never higher than 31 maybe they are did, if the middle pair are never Higher than 12.. look at trios of digits, are they never higher than 365 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try adding a new column which is Date datatype.

Update it using the following query `SELECT CAST('081101' AS DATE)` which returns date format "2008-11-01".

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
DECLARE @Date char(6)
set @Date='081101'
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,SUBSTRING(@Date,5,2)+SUBSTRING(@Date,3,2)+LEFT(@Date,2))
```